# IE goes to http://localhost:36559/ with message "This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server"

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to launch IE but nothing happens with Selenium Java code below:

```
protected WebDriver ieBrowserSetUp() throws Exception {
    // Read the properties file
    Properties prop = getProperties();
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", prop.getProperty("IEDriverPath"));
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.com");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();


    DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
    caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INITIAL_BROWSER_URL, "");

    WebDriver driver= new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);

    System.out.println("Internet Explorer Browser Setup Done Successfully");    
    return driver;
}
```

It is working fine with the Firefox and Chrome Webdriver. I saw in one of the posts the Protected Mode Settings needs to be changed. Is there a workaround as the settings is disabled at work considering I am not a Windows admin. The path is pointed to IEDriverServer.exe I downloaded instead of the "Windows-installed-and-defaulted" IE application.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with this:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", prop.getProperty("IEDriverPath"));

                DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
                caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true); //disable protected mode settings
                caps.setCapability("initialBrowserUrl", url);
                driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);
```